# How to show hide a div based on the existence of cookie

Tags: jsp, cookies, jstl, el

I want to show a div if only a cookie exists. And this is how I code it inside JSP file.

```
<c:if test="${ ! empty cookie['test_cookie']}">
     //some div goes here
   </c:if>
```

but it always shows the div. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check not empty on cookie value: `cookie.test_cookie.value`:

```
<c:if test="${not empty cookie.test_cookie.value}">
```